# Is there an equivalent to SCHEMA.INI for reading Excel Workbooks

Tags: excel, vb.net, schema, oledb

I am currently working on a project that will import data from multiple different sources in a variety of formats and structures - *e.g.*, CSV, fixed-length, *other*-delimited (tab, pipe, etc.) plain-text, and Excel worksheets/workbooks. For this, I'm attempting to build "generic" readers for these files which will throw the files' contents into a `DataTable`/`DataSet` I can use in other methods. The plain-text files are pretty simple as I've created a large `SCHEMA.INI` file which contains field definitions for each of the files the system will handle. That `SCHEMA.INI` resides in a "processing folder" where the files are temporarily stored until their data has been integrated with other systems. A defined text files' data can be easily extracted using this method:

```vb
Private Function TextFileToDataTable(ByVal TextFile As IO.FileInfo) As DataTable
    Dim TextFileData As New DataTable("TextFileData")

    Using TapeFileConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source='" + TextFile.DirectoryName + "';Extended Properties='Text';")
        Using TapeAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0};", TextFile.Name), TapeFileConnect)
            Try
                TapeAdapter.Fill(TextFileData)
            Catch ex As Exception
                TextFileData = Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    Return TextFileData
End Function
```

This works well because a plain-text file isn't terribly complex in its data structure. A single file generally (at least for my requirements) contains, at most, one single table's worth of data - *unless, of course, it's some sort of complex XML or JSON structure file, which can/should be handled completely differently anyway* - so there's no need to go iterating through different elements beyond this.

**NOTE:** *The code above is dependent on the `SCHEMA.INI` file being present in the same directory as the plain-text file being read and there being a section within that `SCHEMA.INI` defined with the same name as that plain-text file.*

**EXAMPLE:**

```
[EXAMPLE_TEXT_FILE.TXT]
CharacterSet=ANSI
Format=FixedLength
ColNameHeader=FALSE
DateTimeFormat="YYYYMMDD"

COL1=CUSTOMER_NUMBER TEXT WIDTH 20
COL2=CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME TEXT WIDTH 30
COL3=CUSTOMER_LASTNAME TEXT WIDTH 40
COL4=CUSTOMER_ADDR1 TEXT WIDTH 40
COL5=CUSTOMER_ADDR2 TEXT WIDTH 40
COL6=CUSTOMER_ADDR3 TEXT WIDTH 40
...
```

Excel workbooks, however, can be a bit trickier. Several of the workbooks I have to process contain multiple worksheets worth of data that I want to consolidate into a single `DataSet` with a `DataTable` for each worksheet. The basic functionality is, again, fairly straightforward and I've come up with the following method to read any and all sheets into a `DataSet`:

```vb
Private Function ExcelFileToDataSet(ByVal ExcelFile As IO.FileInfo, ByVal HasHeaderRow As Boolean) As DataSet
    Dim ExcelFileData As New DataSet("ExcelFileData")
    Dim ExcelConnectionString As String = String.Empty
    Dim UseHeaders As String = "NO"

    Select Case ExcelFile.Extension.ToUpper.Trim
        Case ".XLS"
            ExcelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"
        Case ".XLSX"
            ExcelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"
    End Select

    If HasHeaderRow Then
        UseHeaders = "YES"
    End If

    ExcelConnectionString = String.Format(ExcelConnectionString, ExcelFile.FullName, UseHeaders)

    Try
        Using ExcelConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ExcelConnectionString)
            Dim ExcelSchema As New DataTable

            ExcelConnection.Open()
            ExcelSchema = ExcelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

            For Each ExcelSheet As DataRow In ExcelSchema.Rows
                Dim SheetTable As New DataTable

                Using ExcelAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
                    Dim SheetName As String = ExcelSheet("TABLE_NAME").ToString
                    Dim ExcelCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

                    SheetTable.TableName = SheetName.Substring(0, SheetName.Length - 1)
                    ExcelCommand.Connection = ExcelConnection
                    ExcelCommand.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", SheetName)
                    ExcelAdapter.SelectCommand = ExcelCommand
                    ExcelAdapter.Fill(SheetTable)
                End Using

                ExcelFileData.Tables.Add(SheetTable)
            Next ExcelSheet
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExcelFileData = Nothing
    End Try

    Return ExcelFileData
End Function
```

The above code will work in a majority of the cases I deal with, but my "difficulty" is that there may be some worksheets that have header rows and some that don't *within the same workbook*. Also, for those worksheets that ***do not*** have a header row, I'd like to be able to define the field names and data types similar to how I can with the plain-text `SCHEMA.INI`. The only thing I have going for me in these cases is that the "client" provides me with a data map to help me identify what data elements are in each field.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way similar to the text file's `SCHEMA.INI` to define the structure of an Excel workbook and the worksheet(s) it contains - including column data types to avoid the OleDb driver from "misinterpreting" a column's data - ahead of time. I imagine this could be any sort of structured file such as `INI`, `XML`, or whatever, but it would need to be capable of identifying whether or not a particular sheet contains a header row or, in lieu of such a row, the (*expected*) column definitions. Does any such "standard definition" file exist for Excel workbooks?

**One thing to note:** As you may have noticed in the code for the `ExcelFileToDataSet()` method, I may be dealing with the older `.XLS` (97-03) format or the `.XLSX` (07+) format, so I can't necessarily rely on the workbook being Open XML compliant. I suppose I *could* try breaking the methods out to one for each extension, but I'd rather find something that I can use regardless of which file format the Excel file is using.

Comment: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 will read both .xls and .xlsx just fine. I've never used a Schema.ini so I can't comment really. I specify HDR=No and just discard headers.

Comment: @Ciarán - Thank you for your input. I suppose using the just ACE provider would probably be "better" in the long term. As for discarding the headers, I assume you just reference everything by row/column numbers then? Part of the intended purpose of my question is to be able to identify the columns by name (as well as possibly imposing data type validation) for other methods in my system.

Comment: Yes, but there's no reason you can't run through any headers that are there to determine column order. In fact I do that for quite a lot of variable format files. I also have a generic load program with some config tables. OLEDB is great but it has some quirks relating to data types. It very much relies on well formatted files, - as close to a Table as possible. Also, you get the displayed value returned and not the underlying one.